# How to find out what's freezing my computer

Tags: windows, ssd, freeze

Some time ago (about 2 months) my computer started to freeze randomly (Window 8.1) and after a while (about 5-30sec) it runs again like nothing happened. I suspect the computer is waiting for some IO data (maybe from the ssd) because when it "freezes" I can still move the mouse and some windows still work (can interact with them) but most actions stop for example chrome lets me open new tabs, but won't load pages while "frozen". Some Applications stop responding (I think the do IO stuff in gui thread) but Apps that don't access the ssd drive work just fine while frozen (for example calc.exe)

That said, which tools or options do I have to find out what exactly is causing those random freezes. Eventlog shows nothing suspious sometimes some Applications log infos about the fact that something took very long, but no details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this happen while in Safe Mode?  In order to properly diagnose this problem, you must be able to give me an answer, to that question.

Comment: Those freezes occur randomly and sometimes there are 45min between freezes - I've not tried Safe Mode that long - will give it a shot later. What I am very interested in are tools that are able to hook the winapi and mease the resonsetime to nail it down.

Comment: You need to crash the computer with the keyboard to get a "full" (ensure full dump is created, i.e. same size as memory, user and kernel space) memory dump when it has hung. Set this key up in advance: [MSarticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545499(v=vs.85).aspx) and ensure it works before next hang. Dump in hand, install the Windows SDK to get Debugging tools for Windows, Windbg.exe is the tool.  Configure symbols, load the dump and run: 
*!analyze -v -hang*.  
Hopefully that will provide something.  another command of interest initially would be *!locks*.